# Background-images URL

Tags: html, css

When using the `background-image` I notice that it will not work with images from a direction web page link, like this:

```
body {
 background-image: url("http://www.example.comenter/2312.jpg");
}
```

But if I link it directly from a folder directory it works just fine like such:

```
body {
 background-image: url("C://Users/Jane/Desktop/2312.jpg");
}
```

Why is does it not work with an url link?

Comment: Since there is nothing in `http://www.example.comenter/2312.jpg`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

It works fine with a URL link:

```css
body {
 background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/400x200");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually It works, however you should review if the link is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
body{
   background: url('http://www.example.comenter/2312.jpg');
}
```

If it is not works the following link does not have any image, try another image.

Answer (score 0):

The `background-image` property specifies an image to use as the background of an element.

Just check the link that your are specifying in url may be that path does not consist any image or please check image path that you want to display in webpage.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/130000/velka/pink-simple-background.jpg');
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 style="color:white">Hello World</h1>
</body>

</html>
```